# Php Why does mysql query adds unnecessary extra html tags?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In php i have a SQL query that takes column name and id from table called subjects and will show them on my webpage.

For some reason i am getting extra < a > tag at the end of the first < a > tag. 
Any help?

```
function subjects($id, $name){

   return '<li>' . '<a class="subject-link" href="threads.php?thread=' . $id . '">' . $name  . '<a/>' . '</li>';

}


$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name, id FROM subjects ORDER BY id ASC');
$allFileNames = $stmt->fetchAll();

$x = subjects($allFileNames[0]['id'], $allFileNames[0]['name']);

echo $x;
```

**THIS IS WHAT I GET IN HTML:**

```
<li><a class="subject-link" href="threads.php?thread=12">loodus</a><a></a></li>
```

As you can see there are some unnecessary extra < a > tags at the end of the list.

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT IN HTML:**

```
<li><a class="subject-link" href="threads.php?thread=12">loodus</a></li>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Notice your code...

```
$name . '<a/>' . '</li>';
```

that should be `</a>`.